# I have a sphere that I have added a cell fracture to. I can add a material to one fractured part but how do I add the same material to all of the them

Tags: materials

[image]

Any idea how I add the same material to all of the fractured parts. It would be easy to select all of the parts and add a material but this is blender and its not a simple as that.

Comment: Why not give material first and after that fracture the mesh?

Answer (score 1):

Just select all objects and at last the object with the material you want to apply to all others. Then press CTRL-L -> Materials:

[image]